# Windows 10 shortcuts hotkey not working

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I've added hotkey on my shortcut in Windows10 : 
[image]

But it does not work. Could you please clarify why?

Comment: Are the shortcuts present in the desktop?

Comment: Yes, and set Run as administrator

Comment: May be the specific hotkey is used. Does this happen if you set a different shortcut key?

Comment: Yes, I've tried other hotkeys and got the same result

Comment: Are you sure its not working?

Comment: Of couse yes. It's very strange. I even rebooted my computer and no results.

Comment: To check if CTRL key is stuck/not working, start the OnScreen keyboard and use the keyboard shortcut to launch the program. If it works, then the KB needs replacement. If it doesnt, pls try from safe mode.

Comment: @w32sh What are you talking about? I'm sure that my keyboard works fine.

Comment: Same issue here with a Ctrl + Alt+ L  hotkey
Works like a charm at work, but not on my personnal Windows 10. Also, it _has worked_ at some point. The shortcut target work fine when double clicking on it, and is a folder in my desktop. I also have pinned it to start menu.